# CentOS/Redhat kickstart script cdrom mount point

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, kickstart

Trying to copy some files from my custom CentOS 7 install ISO to the new install in the `%post` section.

I've tried all of these:

```
cp /dev/cdrom/scripts/myscript.sh /etc/myscripts/myscript.sh
cp /dev/cdrom:/scripts/myscript.sh /etc/myscripts/myscript.sh
cp /mnt/sysimage/root/scripts/myscript.sh /etc/myscripts/myscript.sh
cp /scripts/myscript.sh /etc/myscripts/myscript.sh
```

But none of those end up with `myscript.sh` being in `/etc/myscripts`

Where does the install mount the cdrom?

**UPDATE**

I've tried:

```
%post --nochroot

#!/bin/sh

set -x -v

cp -r /run/install/repo/scripts/myscript.sh /mnt/sysimage/etc/httpd/conf/myscript.sh
```

which results in the install not booting (just hangs on the splash)

**UPDATE 2**

Simply doing:

```
%post --nochroot

cp -r /run/install/repo/scripts/myscritp.sh /mnt/sysimage/etc/myscritp.sh

%end
```

Works and the file is copied from the install media `isolinux/scripts` dir to the `/etc` directory on the install target filesystem.

Comment: Unless it changed for EL7, the path for the CD mountpoint is `/mnt/source`. Also, please reconsider placing scripts under `/etc`. (Refer to the [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY).)

Comment: @AaronCopley, you may be thinking of `/mnt/install`, which is (at least as of EL7 when I write this) a symlink to `/run/install`. `/run/install/repo` is indeed where the installation source ISO is mounted. `/mnt/sysimage` is the root of the newly-installed system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `%post` section won't do what you need without some extra work - you need to do this copy inside a `%post --nochroot` section so you have access to the CD. You can probably issue a `mount` command inside `%post`, but using `%post --nochroot` is likely easier. I don't remember the source ISO layout offhand, but it'll be there somewhere.

Comment: I was pretty sure that media was still available under %post, but it's been a while. If this ends up being the case, @Kiksy, make sure to copy to `/mnt/sysimage/etc/myscripts` due to using `nochroot`.